# Rails CKeditor Plugin Validation Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I'm using the Rails ckeditor plugin which includes swfupload. I've also installed the paperclip plugin to handle the actual files (though I don't think it's part of the problem).

I've gotten everything working except that there's no message displayed to the user if it fails validation -- like a file is larger than the specified file size limit. Nothing happens in fact (just silently fails).

I checked the included ckeditor controller that handles the actual upload, and within the *create* method, I see this code block:

```
if @record.valid? && @record.save

    @text = params[:CKEditor].blank? ? @record.to_json : %Q"<script type='text/javascript'>
            window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(#{params[:CKEditorFuncNum]}, '#{escape_single_quotes(@record.url(:content))}');
          </script>"

    format.html { render :text=>@text }
  else
    format.html { render :nothing => true }
  end
```

Looking at this, nothing is rendered back in case of an error. Note that format.html is what runs in either case (valid or invalid record). If the record is valid, it finds that params[:ckeditor] is null so it serializes the record and sends it back as json.

If the model validation fails, swfupload debug output shows that it an event that indicates upload success.

Am I missing something simple? Or was validation never written into the plugin? If not, what needs to be done to get it working? Well, in any case I'd like to get this working. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need rails plugins for CKEditor. What's wrong with using CKEditor by itself?

Comment: The Rails plugin simply wraps the CKEditor in a helper, the provides controllers, a couple of models, and custom handler code for swfupload bundled in. I simply wanted to make use of that instead of writing it from scratch myself. That's not the problem, it works great, except that there was never any error handling code written, or I'm missing something. it's probably more related to the handler code within swfupload (I'm guessing)